# Google sheets script returns N/A from a populated cell

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a query that outputs any rows that match a regex statement:

```
Query('Sheet 1'!D2:H, "select D where H matches '.*{{([0-9])*}}.*'")
```

which is then summarized/condensed in a cell. I then have a script that reads from the summarized cell and emails the cell's content to addresses.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reminders');
  var emails = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var subject = sheet.getRange(2,4).getValue();
  var message = sheet.getRange(2,5).getDisplayValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:emails,subject:subject,htmlBody:message});
```

Unfortunately, even though the query returns values on the actual sheet that is not null, the email just sends #N/A. Maybe the query match runs on the backend before the email is sent? Does anyone have solution?

Comment: Try to add `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before you send mail.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still returning #N/A on the email and I tried putting it at multiple parts of the function.

Comment: Could you make a copy of your sheet and share it? Does the sheet have some values in these cells (2,2) (2,4) (2,5)? Since the task to grab a couple cells and send their content by email doesn't look too difficult. This way you could at the very least to exclude this part of the problem.